# mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 1366 (HY000): Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'risklevel' at row 1

Tags: python, mysql, database, sqldatatypes

[This is the image of my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOj4q.png)

When I run my python code and insert all of the values for my table I receive the error that my risk level has an incorrect integer value

the code for the insert statement is:

```
def register_site():
screen13 = Tk()
sitename_info = sitename2.get()
region_info = region.get()
risklevel_info = risklevel.get()
sitetype_info = sitetype.get()
targetpercent_info = targetpercent.get()
# Sql code for writing the data that was written in the regsitering page. 
cursor = cnn.cursor()
sitequery = "INSERT INTO `sites`(`siteName`,`userID`, `region`, `risklevel`, `siteType`, `target%`) VALUES (%s,null,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
sitequery_vals = (sitename_info, region_info, risklevel_info, sitetype_info, targetpercent_info)
cursor.execute(sitequery, sitequery_vals)
cnn.commit()
cursor.close()
cnn.close()
# removes the values in the entrys once the user selects that the registration was successful
sitename_entry.delete(0, END)
region_entry.delete(0, END)
risklevel_entry.delete(0, END)
sitetype_entry.delete(0, END)
targetpercent_entry.delete(0, END)
Label(screen1, text = "Site Created", fg = "green", font = ("calibri", 11)).pack()
```

Ive attempted to change all the data types to text and the python shell will claim the values have been inserted into the sql table however when you browse through nothing is inserted and the only value there is the siteID which increases.

Comment: Are you sure interger are binded like `%s`? I'm not a python dev, so just see possible problem.

Comment: Yes %s are used for strings while %d is for decimals. I've used %s in another SQL statement for an integer and that statement worked for me.

Comment: Follow the column type. If it is an integer, use %d. In another %s can works when you store numbers in database like strings (char/varchar).

Comment: Ive previously attempted to change all integers to %d and received the error that not all parameters were used.

Comment: Using `%s` is correct - `%d` is using in string formatting, but this is not string formatting.  The most likely cause - without seeing the table structure (`SHOW CREATE TABLE`) and some sample input - is that `risklevel_info` is not an `int`.

Comment: I think %s vs %d and quoting versus not quoting are red herrings.  Show us the data.